# How to make an image fade out without affecting the opacity of a simultaneous bright glow effect

Tags: jquery, image, css, opacity, glow

**EDIT:**

Thanks to tavkomann's help, I got the effects working now as they should. I have also resolved the issue I crossed out below by setting the `padding` of each image's container to `0px.` Hope this helps fellow coders!

<strike>There is just one issue that remains: even though the images do conform to their respective containers in proper alignment, they still do not span the entire width of each; as a result, there is just a strip of space left over on each side.</strike>

Updated code:

```
#main-imgs {
    margin-top: 70px;
}

/* container for each image */

#main-imgs .img-column {
    display: inline-block;      /* conform container to image size */
    overflow: hidden;           /* avoid image-border overlap */

    max-height: 215px;
    padding: 0px;               /* fit image within border */

    border-width: 8px;
    border-radius: 15%;

    border-style: double;
    border-color: #290B01;

box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

/* container hover event */

#main-imgs .img-column:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px white;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}    

/* image */

#main-imgs img {
    vertical-align: middle;    /* rid of space beneath image */
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

/* image hover event */

#main-imgs img:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

**ORIGINAL:**

I'm trying to make an image fade out *and* glow at the same time whenever you hover over it against a black background.

The problem is that when it fades out, its opacity decreases, and this affects all attributes, including `box-shadow.`

As a result, the opacity of the glow effect decreases and extinguishes the glow. So far, the image fades in and out when you hover over and away from it, respectively. I have included the CSS code below.

```
#main-imgs img {
  max-height: 220px;

  border-width: 8px;
  border-radius: 15%;

  border-style: double;
  border-color: #290B01;

  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

#main-imgs img:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

I have two possible (concurrent) solutions in mind, but have yet to find a way to implement either:

1. create an "underlay," a `div` under the image that casts its own unadulterated glow
2. use something other than the `hover` pseudo-class and the `opacity` attribute to simulate and isolate the fade effect (e.g. use jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I will show an implementation for this solution:

> create an "underlay," a div under the image that casts its own unadulterated glow

First of all, we need to create a structure for the "underlay". This is simply a parent container:

```
<div class="img">
  <img src="URL" alt="description" />
</div>
```

Now, just add the `border` and the `border-radius` to the parent container instead of the image. In order for the container to adapt to the size of the image, we have to use `display: inline-block`. We also need to set `overflow: hidden` so that the image fits to the `border-radius` of the container. Last but not least, we should use `vertical-align: middle` for the image, [so there is not a space at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image).

Finally, this leads us to the following code example in which both, the fade out and the glow effect, work correctly:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 8px double #290B01;
  border-radius: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img > img {
  max-height: 220px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img > img:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="description" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, tavkomann! The effects work great now. Earlier, I asked about how to get rid of the space that's left over on each side of the image within its border, but I resolved it by setting `padding` to `0px.`